# Data Studio Connector can't get access token for BigQuery Service Account: Access not granted or expired

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-oauth, looker-studio, service-accounts

I'm trying to make a community connector to connect my database in BigQuery to data studio with the service account that I hooked up as the Owner/DataViewer/JobUser of the BigQuery project.  I know that the service account works when connecting to BigQuery because I've tested it elsewhere.  I copied from the connector code from this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/blocks/using-service-accounts) almost exactly, replacing the SQL string with my query and adding some different query parameters.  I also stored the service account's credentials in my script properties by pasting the json object and storing it like:

```
var service_account_creds_obj = {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": ...
    ...
}
scriptProperties.setProperty('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDS', JSON.stringify(service_account_creds_obj));
```

However, I always get stuck in the flow when my getData function calls `getOauthService().getAccessToken()`, which doesn't ever successfully return.  When I create a report using the connector, I get this error: "Access not granted or expired."  I can't find the documentation for getAccessToken and I'm having trouble understanding why it won't terminate.  I can see that it doesn't return because a console.log immediately before that line displays but it never gets to the log on the next line. Then my try-catch block catches the error that I'm seeing.  Note that my getOauthService function is exactly the same as the one from the documentation/tutorial example, except that I've played around with the input text in the call to createService.  That input text shouldn't really matter though right?

Please, I've been trying to debug this for hours, but the documentation on this is pretty horrible, and it's really hard to debug since the flow of the code is handled in the background and stackdriver logging is really buggy.

Comment: Code is [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/ade8b9a8c5e8117ea18bcd14fcd1bb779a3425f8/src/Service.js#L452) and <= [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/ade8b9a8c5e8117ea18bcd14fcd1bb779a3425f8/src/Service.js#L411) Try `Service.getLastError()`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.  The documentation posted above said to set the OAuth2 scope to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly.  However, I naively included

`"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly"]`

in my manifest file.  Meanwhile, the code I copied over from the documentation already included this line:

```
.setScope(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly']);
```

So I'm not sure exactly why this caused a problem.  But it must have prevented the OAuth2.createService function from properly getting set.

Comment: The scope in the manifest works with the user's token that you can get via `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`. However, for the service account's token's scope, you will need to define that in your code when you use the oAuth2 library using `.setScope`.

Comment: If you set that in manifest, external_access scope, which is needed to use urlfetch/access http would have been blocked